# How to change the server name?

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008-r2

I am a new employee in one of the web development companies. My company has the following policy in developing the web-based applications:
The database should be resided on coporate server which is controlled by IT
and the web-based application files should be hosted on another different server which I have the admin rights on it. We have Windows Server 2008 R2. To access one of these applications, we should put as a link the server name such as:

```
http://ServerName.myapplication
```

**Instead of the server name, I want to put a meaningful name (or alias) but I don't know how to do that. So could you please tell me how to do this?**

By the way, I searched in the Internet about it and all of the resources talking about the DNS without clear steps.

Comment: If you are okay with changing your Server Name, then that will the best way to handle it I think

Comment: Ok how to change the server name?

Comment: just added the answer for changing the server name

Answer (score 0):

To change the server/computer name follow the following steps:

1. Go to My Computer --> Properties
2. Click "Change Settings" --> Opens the "System Properties" window
3. Click "Change" --> Opens "Computer Name/Domain Changes" window
4. Change the "Computer Name" there and click "OK"

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your local computers `hosts` file to use custom DNS that only applies to your workstation.

File: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Format: `<ip address to resolve to> <custom dns name>`

Example: `192.168.1.2 meaningfulalias.com`

Now you can go to `meaningfulalias.com` on your workstation and it will go to whatever IP you really want.